# How do I get RouteData in Application_EndRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a simple performance logger that hooks in to `Application_EndRequest` / `Application_BeginRequest`

I would like to send my logger the name of the *action* and *controller* as some sort of key.

How can I access this information? (Don't mind if I have to intercept it earlier on and keep it around in the context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that you can.

I poked around the `HttpContext.Current` and found that on the second (and subsequent requests), the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection contains an instance of a `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.RequestData` class.  Unfortunately, this class is private so you can't access its data.  In the debugger, however, it seems that this contains the information you're looking for (not sure why it doesn't exist on the first request though).

Alternatively, could you just use an action filter and add that to a BaseController class that all of your controllers derive from?  Something like:

```
public class LoggingActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        var controllerName = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
    }
}
```

Then create a base controller class with this attribute:

```
[LoggingAction]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: yerp ... we are inheriting off a base controller so the ActionFilter approach works

Comment: btw, we already had an override of `Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)` so I placed the code that stuffs it in the context there. Seems to work fine.

Comment: it does not work if we want to change the language in the current thread. (Tested only in MVC 3...). Do you have any idea how we could use the route data to change the language ?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but you can access the requested information using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("controller")
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("action")
```

Comment: `RouteData.Values` is a `Dictionary` and its entries will be available using square brackets instead of parentheses: 
`HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]`
and
`HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]`

Answer (score 2):

This is working:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var rd = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);
        // use rd

    }
```

Comment: works perfectly. That was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 object GetControllerFromContext(HttpContext context) {
        object controller = null;
        HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        RouteData routeData = urlHelper.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(currentContext);
        if(routeData != null) {
            controller = routeData.Values["controller"];
        }
        return controller;
    }
```